# Using Grep to multiple find and replace

Tags: command-line, 15.04, grep, html, web-development

I have lets say 90 HTML files and I have to put one new JS script link to head section each of them. Now, i could use some F&R engine of some code compiler

Like:

```
find: </head>
replace it with: link to JS script</head>
```

But I don't like this solution cause code is mess after that.

I was wondering - how can I use grep to insert new script link right before  tag in all .html files in specific dir ?

Comment: Why down vote :( ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`grep` doesn't replace or modify files.  Use `sed`:

```
sed -i 's|</head>|link to JS script</head>|' *.html
```

#### How it works

`-i` tells sed to modify files in place.

The most important `sed` command is substitute.  It has the form `s|old|new|` where `old` is a regular expression.  Here, we replace `</head>` with `link to JS script</head>`.

`*.html` tells sed to operate on all html files that the shell finds in the current directory.

Comment: Nice :) ! Thank you for clarify this . It will help me a lot in future

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
for q in *.html
do
  ex -sc '%s.</head>.link to JS script&.|x' "$q"
done
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `x` save and close